# Reading values from keyboard ​to save them to an array

Tags: java, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

The idea is enters numbers from keyboard to save them into an array:

```
public void set_numbersQ() {
    ArrayList<int[]> lf = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] fraction= new int[1];
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        try {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            fraction[i] = Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());
        }
        catch(Exception e){} 
    }
    lf.add(fraction);
    System.out.println(fraction[0] + " / " + fraction[1] );

}
```

This code give me an error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1.

Because `fraction[0]` is saved correctly but `fraction[1]` it's not. I think the error could be in `InputStreamReader` or in `BufferedReader` because the try is executed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stream reader should be opened at once and `fraction` size must be `2`.

```java
    public static void set_numbersQ() {
        int[] fraction = new int[2];
        try (InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in)) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
            fraction[0] = scanner.nextInt();
            fraction[1] = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println(fraction[0] + " / " + fraction[1] + " = " + (fraction[0] / fraction[1]));
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
```